# How to create multiple list in single column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can i get below structure in dataframe of multiple list of length.

```
                    Col1
0         [SF, NYG, 123]
1  [SF, NYG, test, test]
2         [SF, NYG, foo]
3              [SF, NYG]
4          [SF, NYG, 45]
5              [SF, NYG]
6          [SF, NYG, 32]
```

Comment: What are input data? maybe need only `df['col'].str.split(',')` if one string column separated by `,`

Comment: @jezrael with an `expand=True`...

Comment: @JonClements - If add expand=True get dataframe I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpliest is use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) if input is one column with values separated by separator like `|`:

```
df['lists'] = df['Col1'].str.split('|')
print (df)
               Col1                  lists
0        SF|NYG|123         [SF, NYG, 123]
1  SF|NYG|test|test  [SF, NYG, test, test]
2        SF|NYG|foo         [SF, NYG, foo]
3            SF|NYG              [SF, NYG]
4         SF|NYG|45          [SF, NYG, 45]
5            SF|NYG              [SF, NYG]
6         SF|NYG|32          [SF, NYG, 32]
```